# Exempt GoogleBot from throttling (1.x)

Tags: ee1

Old school knowledge needed:

The IP-based method of exempting GoogleBot from throttling (as detailed in the MIA EE wiki) no longer works - GoogleBot doesn't have a fixed IP range.

I need Google to be able to constantly and reliably index a news site, but would like to keep throttling active, to help deal with weak DOS nonsense.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at changing this in Google's configs directly. If you set up a Webmaster Tools account and connect the domain, you can adjust the [**Crawl Rate**](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48620) to something that will work better for your site.

[image]

Comment: A great tip, but this site has been assigned special crawl rates because of the amount and frequency of new content. Google won't allow changing the settings in Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Assigned how? So this setting is disabled on your end?

Comment: No, on Google's. They do that for news sites with heaps of new content.

Comment: To be clear, the setting in Webmaster Tools doesn't affect the frequency of the bot visits, instead it allows you to change the speed at which the bot consumes pages on the site while it's there visiting. You can slow the speed down to fit within your throttling limits. Apparently, if you set this you need to readd it every 90 days.

Comment: And if you have a site with frequent enough updates, Google apparently disables any ability to modify any crawl settings.

"Crawl rate Your site has been assigned special crawl rate settings. You will not be able to change the crawl rate."