# Does Throttling affect "good" bots negatively?

Tags: htaccess, security, config

Throttling limits, "the number of page requests by a single IP address within a given time interval." In the ebook Securing ExpressionEngine 2, Mark Huot writes that, "[Throttling is] one of the first settings you should enable when securing an EE2 install."

The EllisLab user guide doesn't give too much information about it: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/throttling.html

Throttling helps block malicious bots, but does it affect "good" bots like Googlebot, Yahoo Slurp, and MSNbot? If so, is there a way to allow these latter kinds of bots -- maybe with a hidden configuration variable or with some .htaccess code?

[NOTE: I saw this: [Exempt GoogleBot from throttling (1.x)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/exempt-googlebot-from-throttling-1-x) Is it true website owners have to seek out bot sites like this one manually, or can this be accomplished with .htaccess?]

[UPDATE: So far it seems like the best option is adding this to .htaccess:

User-agent: *

Crawl-delay: 5

And customized the setting in Google Webmaster Tools: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en ]

Comment: You can also do something similar in Bing: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302